# Is there a way to change the font in Adobe Bridge's Content pane?

Tags: adobe-bridge

I don't know if its the new OS (Windows 7) or the new monitor I just got here but I'm having a lot of trouble reading the files in the CONTENT section of Bridge.

Is there a way to change the font? Right now it looks to be defaulting on a very narrow, small font. Zooming in and out helps a little but not much. If I zoom all the way out so only one file is displayed in the content at a time with a very long scroll bar its probably 11 pt Arial Narrow for the folder/file name.

Comment: Seems liked a very good reason to avoid Adobe products. It seems like they are trying to make them hard for people with poor eyesight to manage,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this has posted as a [Suggestion in the Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4028239) in 2011, subsequently added in the [Feedback Section](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/problem_with_hi_res_monitors) as "*Photoshop: Support scalable user interface UI for high resolution monitors*".

Seems like there is no 'native' way to do it yet.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a workaround but you can do disable High DPI support for bridge.exe by using an external manifest file.  To do this you need to edit your windows registry to enable external manifest files:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > SideBySide

Add a DWORD called "PreferExternalManifest" and set it to "1"

Now create the in the same folder as bridge.exe create a file name bridge.exe.manifest with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">

<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
      version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"
      publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
      language="*">
    </assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT"
      version="9.0.21022.8"
      processorArchitecture="amd64"
      publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
    </assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel
        level="asInvoker"
        uiAccess="false"/>
    </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
</trustInfo>

<asmv3:application>
  <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
    <ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware xmlns:ms_windowsSettings="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware>
  </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>

</assembly>
```

Now launch bridge.exe and the fonts should now be easy to read.

If you want more detailed instructions I wrote them out here:

http://visihow.com/Increase_Font_Size_in_Adobe_Bridge_on_a_High_Resolution_4k_Graphics_Card_and_Monitor_So_It_Is_Not_Too_Small_to_Read_Text

Please note you will need to edit your windows registry which some users may not be comfortable with.

Comment: Hi user1254723, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: Hi Vincent.  I added as much detail as I could above.  I dont have time to redo all the screenshots i did in the wiki but for more advanced users this will help them.  For less technically adept users they should go through the wiki.